# Lifecycle of Controllers

Tags: force.com-sites, controller, visualforce

I am just wondering about the life cycle of page controllers? How often are than instantiated and is there any configurations which can change this?

Is there a method guaranteed to be invoked every time a page which uses the controller is displayed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The docs have a detailed section explaining the order of execution for Visualforce pages:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_lifecycle.htm

Answer (score 0):

> Once a new get request is made by the user, the view state and controller objects are deleted.
>
> If the user interaction requires a page update, such as when the user clicks a Save button that triggers a save action, a postback request is made. For more information on postback requests, see Order of Execution for Visualforce Page Postback Requests.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_get_request.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_postback_request.htm